# Disable setting an attribute of python extension object

Tags: c++, python

I've created a Python Extension following the [Defining New Types](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/newtypes.html) guide.

At one point, it says to define `getters` and `setters` for the new type's attributes using an `PyGetSetDef[]`. I've done this, but these getters and setters are ignored, and I'm not sure why.

Currently, I have code that works like this:

```
import new_ext_obj
test = new_ext_obj.init("string") # sets the 'name' attribute of the new object
test.name # returns "string"
test.name = "what" #
test.name # returns "what"
```

I'm trying to make it so that `test.name = "what"` will not work - I don't want this attribute to be changeable after it has been initialized. My setter is being ignored, however, so I don't know how to accomplish this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that you need to create a `setattr` function as detailed [here](http://starship.python.net/crew/arcege/extwriting/pyext.html).